# Member function of class with template arguments and default arguments outside class

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, definition

I want to define function outside the template class as described below.

Already tried a lot of combinations for the second argument which is a template and takes default argument as well.

```
template <typename T>
class CustomAllocator
{
 //My custom allocator
};

template <typename T, typename Allocator = CustomAllocator<T> >
class CustomContainer
{
 void push_back();
};

/*I want to define push_back outside my class, tried everything.
Almost 4 hours spent through stackoverflow, fluentcpp and all sites*/

// What should be specified for Allocator here ?
template <typename T>
void CustomContainer<T,Allocator>::push_back(T value)
{

}

//OR

template <typename T>
void CustomContainer<T,CustomAllocator<> >::push_back(T value)
{

}
```

I expect it to be defined outside class
Actual getting compiler error, if it is simple type I could easily mention int,float etc. in the second argument.

Comment: `template <typename T, typename Allocator>`

Comment: In the template definition, `push_back()` takes no arguments. The two attempted definitions of that function both take an argument. In the template class, change the function declaration to `void push_back(DataType);` (assuming that `DataType` has been defined somewhere; it doesn't appear in the sample code anywhere.

Comment: Sorry for that DataType confusion, it is basically of type T, I have edited the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of your class definition, it will be unclear to a function what type `Allocator` is, so you have to redeclare it just like you redeclared `T`

```
template <class T, class Allocator>
void CustomContainer<T,Allocator>::push_back(T value)
{
   // ...
}
```

(I'm assuming that `DataType` should be `T`)

Note that your declaration of `push_back`, in the class should match the definition:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator = CustomAllocator<T> >
class CustomContainer
{
 void push_back(T);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a ton !! I corrected that to T.
How did you arrive at it ? I mean why not Allocator<> which I was trying , since Allocator is template type although it is default parameter.
Wonderful Answer, at least for me !!
They say that default types need not be mentioned in the definition, I tried it once but then the compiler error appeared, but may be then the argument being specified was not Allocator and something like Allocator<>.

Comment: Hard to say how I arrived at it... Years of experience I guess? As for why not `Allocator<>`. That code is trying to use a version of `Allocator` with defaulted template arguments, which it doesn't have so it will not compile (besides, you wouldn't want it anyway)

Comment: @Robust `Allocator` is not a template.  It may be a type _instantiated from_ a template, but it is not itself a template.

Comment: Hmm...yes it is a type initiated from a template, a template which is neither fully specialized nor partially, such type has to be a template, since it very much acts and behaves like a template. Any type of CustomAllocator it can take as second argument,in case, we do not provide that, it will take the default one.
I understand what you mean to say from syntax point of view, but I cannot agree that it is not a template itself.

Answer (score 2):

You may not use default template arguments for a member function of a template defined outside the template definition.

From the C++ 17 Standard (17.1 Template parameters)

> 12. ... A default template-argument shall not be specified in the template-
>       parameter-lists of the definition of a member of a class
>       template that appears outside of the member’s class.

So just write

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
void CustomContainer<T, Allocator>::push_back( const T &value )
{
    //...
}
```

Pay attention to the argument of the function. Your declaration of the function does not correspond to its definition.

Comment: But this is default template argument for the template class and not for a particular member function of this template class right ? And if we cannot define it outside the class, we just have been able to do so. I mean it should be binary either we can or we cannot, This may is confusing.

Comment: @Robust Yes, and it can not be used in a member function definition. That is all template parameters of the class shall be specified in a member function definition outside the template class.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks a lot! The below line was enlightening.
"That is all template parameters of the class shall be specified in a member function definition outside the template class."

Comment: @Robust It would be more correctly to say that all templates parameters and all template arguments for the class of a defined member function shall be specified